# is interference control responsible for sensory sensitivities?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

In practice, reduced interference control  looks like difficulties with screening out background noise, visual distractors etc. does this account for sensory sensitives found in e.g. ASD? Or is that a separate matter? Thanks